# Facing SQL Error [600] [60000]: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [HO define: Long fetch] - SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dblink

Below is the scenario:

**Source**: Oracle 19.3.0.0.0

**Target**: MySQL 8.0.22-13

We have created DBLINK from Oracle to MySQL using DG4ODBC Database Link. (Followed Doc ID 1320645.1)
We are able to connect and select from Oracle to MySQL, however we are facing below issues:

1. When connecting from Oracle SQL Prompt, it works fine as shown below:

> ```
> SQL> select * from "ocsweb"."sounds"@myodbc5;
>
>         ID HARDWARE_ID MANUFACTURER                                                                     NAME                                      DESCRIPTION
> ---------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>          1        2313 Microsoft                                                                        High Definition Audio Device              High Definition Audio Device
>          2        2313 Intel(R) Corporation                                                             Intel(R) Display Audio                    Intel(R) Display Audio
>
> SQL>
> ```

2. However, when I try to execute the same SQL from SQL developer or when connecting to the database using Python and cx_oracle, we see below error:

> ```
> SQL Error [600] [60000]: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments:
> [HO define: Long fetch], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []¶
> ```

3. When we try to SELECT with only one varchar data type columns, it returns data fine.

Comment: The could be a problem with the quoting. Show your Python code.

Comment: ora-0600 means - _by definition_ - that you hit an "unhandled exception" (aka: a bug).  The only resolution is to use your paid support to log on to My Oracle Support, then search 'ora-0600' to get a lookup tool to see if there is a fix for the specific issue, as identified by the first argument in the error message.  If that doesn't lead to a resolution, you have to open a Service Request.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, **“SQL Error [600] [60000]: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [HO define: Long fetch]”** has been fixed now. (When fetching more than one VARCHAR columns)

We are now able to select multiple VARCHAR datatype columns without oracle engine converting it to LONG. (I have tested from SQL Developer and DBeaver tools)
We have included below parameters in the initialization file of odbc instance to fix the issue:

**HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE=LOCAL** (Specifies whether to suppress ratio expansion when computing the length of (VAR)CHAR datatypes during data conversion from the non-Oracle database to the gateway, and then to the Oracle database. When it is set to LOCAL, the expansion is suppressed between the gateway and the Oracle database.)

**HS_NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR** (When set to CHAR, the (VAR)CHAR columns of non-oracle database are to be interpreted as having CHAR semantics)

Answer (score 1):

`HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE=LOCAL` solved my problem with a PostgreSQL database which has a table with 2 fields varchar(500)